# Linux driver DM9621A for USB to ethernet adapter not compile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, drivers, ethernet

I'm using xubuntu 18.04 with Linux kernel 4.18.0-18-generic.

Recently I bought a USB 2.0 to Ethernet adapter for my notebook, but I encountered some problems on installing the DM9621 driver. Because the built-in driver is DM9601, I take the source code from the vendor to compile. But when I try to run make, I got some errors:

```
$ make
make -C /lib/modules/4.18.0-18-generic/build M=/home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620  
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-18-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620/dm9620.o
/home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620/dm9620.c:557:18: error: ‘usbnet_get_settings’ undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean ‘usbnet_get_stats64’?
  .get_settings = usbnet_get_settings,
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  usbnet_get_stats64
/home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620/dm9620.c:558:18: error: ‘usbnet_set_settings’ undeclared here (not in a function); did you mean ‘usbnet_get_settings’?
  .set_settings = usbnet_set_settings,
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
                  usbnet_get_settings
/home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620/dm9620.c: In function ‘dm9620_bind’:
/home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620/dm9620.c:712:2: warning: this ‘else’ clause does not guard... [-Wmisleading-indentation]
  else
  ^~~~
/home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620/dm9620.c:715:3: note: ...this statement, but the latter is misleadingly indented as if it were guarded by the ‘else’
   printk("++++++[dm962]+++++  [Analysis.2] 0xF2, D[7] %d %s\n", tmp>>7, (tmp&(1<<7))? "Err: RX Unexpected condition": "OK" );
   ^~~~~~
scripts/Makefile.build:330: recipe for target '/home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620/dm9620.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620/dm9620.o] Error 1
Makefile:1534: recipe for target '_module_/home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/shootingstar/Downloads/Linux/Linux/lnx_dm9620] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.18.0-18-generic'
Makefile:37: recipe for target 'default' failed
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

The driver source code can be downloaded here: [DM9621A Linux_USB-Ethernet.exe](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B4BsRkIKQqdla29pWDRPM05LQ0E?fbclid=IwAR2bpma9AUz85_fyV5hg9rLzDZ1BuRfr2ZMXm17Ba1lWX1l7ywzEewmaNQQ)

I'm not familiar with Linux Driver and C Programming, and how do I fix these problems?

Comment: The driver files you are trying to install seem to have unmet dependencies. Perhaps you could try installing those dependencies via "sudo apt install [package]". If the package cannot be found on its own, aptitude should suggest another package which may include it.

Answer (score 0):

The driver you're trying to build was written in 2009 -- it is now nearly ten years old, and is not compatible with current versions of the Linux kernel. Updating it to build (and work!) on a modern kernel is beyond the scope of this site.

Despite the mismatched name, the dm9601 driver present in the kernel should handle DM9621 devices. (It actually handles a small family of Davicom DM96xx USB network devices.) If you're having trouble getting this driver to work, ask a new question with details about the problems you're having.